# Пагинация страниц в Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

Используется Laravel 5.2

База данных содержит 3 таблицы:

1 - interiors

2 - categories

3 - interiors_categories

Третья таблица создана для связи первых двух через id.

```
Schema::create('interiors_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('id_interior')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('id_category')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('id_interior')->references('id')->on('interiors');
        $table->foreign('id_category')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
```

Для связи используется модель

```
class Interior extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'interiors';
     public function categories()
     {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category', 'interiors_categories', 'id_interior', 'id_category');
     }
}
```

Ну и существует еще модель Category, с методом interiors.
Вывожу все интерьеры через команду

```
$interiors = Interiors::with('categories')->paginate(5);
```

Пагинация прекрасно отрабатывает и выводит по очереди 5 записей с данными о категории интерьера.

Но пытаюсь уже вторые сутки сделать наоборот. То есть по выбранной 1 категории вывести все интерьеры через пагинацию. Получается вытянуть их только все вместе.
[image: test]

Жду Вашей помощи в этом вопросе.

Comment: Причем тут пагинация, вы выводите список всех интерьеров с категориями. Вам нужно выводить с обратной стороны `Category::find($id)->interiors->paginate(5)`

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли в модель Category добавить метод для связи,

```
class Category extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'categories';
     public function interiors()
     {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Interior', 'interiors_categories', 'id_category', 'id_interior');
     }
}
```